# Inject some CSS containing PHP on JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to get some CSS containing PHP on jQuery. 
I basically need this CSS:

```
background: #3c653c url( <?php echo $cta_background_image_url; ?> ) no-repeat fixed;
```

Applied to:

```
wp.customize( 'cta_background_image', function( value ) {
    var styles = {
          backgroundPosition : "center top",
          backgroundBlendMode: "hard-light",
          position: "relative",
          height: "440px",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          lineHeight: "200%",
          color: "#fff",
          overflow: "hidden",
          paddingTop: "0",
          marginBottom: "0"
        };
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $( '.cta-parallax-section ' ).css( 'background', 'url( ' + to + ')' );
        $( '.cta-parallax-section ' ).css( styles );
    } );
});
```

I need too inject the code  where it says css( 'background', 'url( ' + to + ')' );

This code will be applied to a WordPress Customizer to make it render changes made by the user in real time within the preview window.

How can I achieve this? I can't find information online on this kind of maneuver.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from the variable `$cta_background_image_url;` you can simply set a timeout and retrieve the value from the element, which you can use for whatever you want.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var data = $("background").css("background-image");
}, 50);
```

The variable `data` would output `url( [ value from $cta_background_image_url ] )`.

To inject it, simply use the variable `data`:

```
$( '.cta-parallax-section ' ).css( 'background', data );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I did not explain myself good enough. What I really need is this:   background: #3c653c url( <?php echo $cta_background_image_url; ?> ) no-repeat fixed;      injected here:  $( '.cta-parallax-section ' ).css( 'background', // that code here  );    but I ignore the correct syntax. Every time I try some different options I end up with an error. Would you mind sharing how you would go about that? thanks again so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can put some vars in head with this code:

`add_action('wp_head', function(){
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var bg_img = '<?php echo $bg_img; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
});`

And use bg_img var in your js code. But better way is using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, I think I did not explain myself good enough. what I need is this Hexadecimal color #3c653c which is controlled by this php:`<?php echo get_theme_mod('team_img_filter'); ?>`inside of this: `$( '.cta-parallax-section ' ).css( 'background', '//here whatever syntax I need to insert the previus php url( ' + to + ')' );` thank you I have tried so many things and I can't get it right..

Comment: With code from my example you can set value of your color to js var. And then set this val like this:   
`$('.cta-parallax-section').css('background', bg_img);`